# Laravel eloquent always get 500 response

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Please help me, after can't sleep because this code always get response 500, whats wrong with this ?

```php
public function getInfoPelunasan(Request $request)
{
    $id_fasilitas = $request -> id_fasilitas;

    $tunggakan = DB::table('kredit_fasilitas')
        ->leftJoin(DB::raw("(SELECT sum(jumlah) as jumlah, id_fasilitas
                            FROM kredit_transaksi
                            WHERE (tipe = 'AI' OR tipe = 'MD')
                            AND id_fasilitas = $id_fasilitas
                            group by id_fasilitas) as kt"), 'id', '=',    'kt.id_fasilitas')
        ->leftJoin(DB::raw("(SELECT sum(jumlah) as jumlah, id_fasilitas
                            FROM kredit_transaksi
                            WHERE (tipe = 'BMB' OR tipe = 'BMD')
                            AND id_fasilitas = $id_fasilitas
                            group by id_fasilitas) as kd"), 'no_fasilitas', '=', 'kd.id_fasilitas')
        ->where('id', '=', $id_fasilitas);

    $tunggakan= $tunggakan -> get();

    return response()->json([
        "success" => true,
        "message" => "Info pelunasan retrieved successfully.",
        "data" => $tunggakan
    ]);
}
```

I want to convert this query to laravel eloquent, but never success

```sql
SELECT *
FROM kredit_fasilitas
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(jumlah) AS jumlah, id_fasilitas
    FROM kredit_transaksi
    WHERE (tipe = 'AI' OR tipe = 'MD')
    AND id_fasilitas = '139019285'
    GROUP BY id_fasilitas
) AS kt ON id = kt.id_fasilitas
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sum(jumlah) as jumlah, id_fasilitas
    FROM kredit_transaksi
    WHERE (tipe = 'BMB' OR tipe = 'BMD')
    AND id_fasilitas = '139019285'
    GROUP BY id_fasilitas
) AS kd ON no_fasilitas = kd.id_fasilitas
WHERE id = '139019285';
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Are you trying to directly access a DB from your front end react native code?  NEVER DO THAT.  It's COMPLETELY insecure.  In order to do that, you need to embed the password to the db in your app.  That means anyone who downloads your app has access to the password, and can use it to delete or fake any data they wish.  NEVER directly access your server side DB from client code.  Instead, use an intermediate webservice.

Comment: Did you turn on Debug? Can your provide more content of errors?

Comment: error just like this : [Error: Request failed with status code 500]

Comment: I think you could see a more details error on you devtools section on the browser.

Make sure you the debug entry in the .env file is set to true,

Once you get the details errors, more people could help you

Comment: Can you show us an attempt that results in a 500 error?

Comment: In the future, please do not add irrelevant tags to your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please check the error message in the `storage/logs` folder! Or set the value of `APP_DEBUG` to `true` in the `.env` file and reproduce the issue!

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me, i just want to know what if my code is wrong on syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have to deal with subqueries in laravel, first isolate and convert them.

Think of your SQL query like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM kredit_fasilitas
LEFT JOIN (-SUBQUERY1-) AS kt ON id = kt.id_fasilitas
LEFT JOIN (-SUBQUERY2-) AS kd ON no_fasilitas = kd.id_fasilitas
WHERE id = '139019285';
```

It ends up looking really simple.

#### Subquery for LEFT JOIN 1

```sql
SELECT
  SUM(jumlah) AS jumlah,
  id_fasilitas
FROM
  kredit_transaksi
WHERE
  (tipe = 'AI' OR tipe = 'MD')
  AND id_fasilitas = '139019285'
GROUP BY
  id_fasilitas
```

#### Subquery for LEFT JOIN 2

```sql
SELECT
  SUM(jumlah) AS jumlah,
  id_fasilitas
FROM
  kredit_transaksi
WHERE
  (tipe = 'BMB' OR tipe = 'BMD')
  AND id_fasilitas = '139019285'
GROUP BY
  id_fasilitas
```

Now that you have them isolated, write them using the query builder.

```php
// subquery for LEFT JOIN 1
$sub1 = DB::query()
    ->select(
        DB::raw('SUM(jumlah) AS jumlah'),
        'id_fasilitas',
    )
    ->from('kredit_transaksi')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('tipe', 'AI')->orWhere('tipe', 'MD');
    })
    ->where('id_fasilitas', $id_fasilitas)
    ->groupBy('id_fasilitas'); // do not call get(). We're only interested in the Builder object, not the results
```

```php
// subquery for LEFT JOIN 2
$sub2 = DB::query()
    ->select(
        DB::raw('SUM(jumlah) AS jumlah'),
        'id_fasilitas',
    )
    ->from('kredit_transaksi')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('tipe', 'BMB')->orWhere('tipe', 'BMD');
    })
    ->where('id_fasilitas', $id_fasilitas)
    ->groupBy('id_fasilitas'); // do not call get(). We're only interested in the Builder object, not the results
```

Notice how much the result looks like SQL.

Finally, now that you've got your subqueries, you can use

```
leftJoinSub($query, $as, $first, $operator, $second)
```

```php
$results = DB::query()
    ->select('*')
    ->from('kredit_fasilitas')
    ->leftJoinSub($sub1, 'kt', 'id', '=', 'kt.id_fasilitas')
    ->leftJoinSub($sub2, 'kd', 'no_fasilitas', '=', 'kd.id_fasilitas')
    ->where('id', $id_fasilitas)
    ->get();
```

I wrote the query like this to make it look as much as possible to SQL but there are a few things that can be removed. `select('*')` is implied even if it's not present. Also `DB::table(...)` is the same as `DB::query()->from(...)` and finally, there's no need to specify the operator if it's `'='`.

```php
$results = DB::table('kredit_fasilitas')
    ->leftJoinSub($sub1, 'kt', 'id', 'kt.id_fasilitas')
    ->leftJoinSub($sub2, 'kd', 'no_fasilitas', 'kd.id_fasilitas')
    ->where('id', $id_fasilitas)
    ->get();
```